# code signing the installer

Tags: installation, nsis, code-signing

I have received an code signing certificate which i used to sign my NSIS installer. I can see the verified publisher as my company name in the UAC screen in the system[in Windows 7] which I signed the installer.

But when tested in other computers[in XP] my company name is not showing in the place of verified publisher.

Can you please advice me on why is it behaving differently  in various computers?

Thanks in advance,
John.

Comment: You are using the signing tools from the Windows SDK?

Comment: no  i've done it using signcode.exe which i downloaded from https://www.cryptguard.com/files/codesigningx86.exe

Comment: On older Windows versions (XP for example) the digital signature information is not always shown. It's usually shown when launching a file from a network location or from a browser. If you launch the file directly and no information is shown (the installer simply starts), it's the normal behavior.

Comment: no issues. it was testers fault. everything is working fine. Thanks everyone helped.

Answer (score 1):

We also noticed that this happens on older systems that are not completely updated. 
There is one security update which includes new root certificates, if this update is not installed your certificate won't be recognized as "trusted".

If run all windwos updates on them the publisher will be recognized.

Very unfortunate but as far as I know there is no way around.